# Copied animate() example straight out of JQuery manual and it renders errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some strange behaviors with bits of JQuery code being removed when it renders in the browser. I am trying to use the .animate(), and to test I copied an example straight out of the JQuery manual and it throws errors.

My code:

```
function change_trend(){

    $('#trends_holder').animate({
      left: "50px", opacity: 1
    }, { duration: 500, queue: false });

    }
```

What actually gets rendered in the browser:

```
function change_trend(){
    $('#trends_holder').animate({
       left: "50px", 
       opacity: 1
    }, );
}
```

The error:

```
Unexpected token: )
```

WTF is going on?

Comment: It looks kind-of like it's saying, "Hey thanks for that token; I didn't expect it!" and smiling at you.

Comment: Also that code works just fine for me, though my browser seems less delighted.

Comment: haha. It looks like it's saying - hey I'm JQuery and I'm going to be an a$$hole today. If I leave just one parameter in, it renders fine but it doesn't do anything. If I add a second parameter, it removes all the data from one of the parameters.

Comment: Do you have a page we can look at?

Comment: How exactly are you seeing this code get mangled?  Are you just doing a "view source"?

Comment: yes - just using "inspect element" in chrome to view the error and reading what it posts.

Comment: In what browser? and what version of jQuery are you using? I tried to run your code in jsfiddle, and it worked fine..

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes around the object keys: `{ 'duration': 500, 'queue': false }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you're writing isn't the issue.  This works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/entropo/6YN8q/

Some part of how your code is getting saved or sent to the browser is clearly broken though.  Are you just running the code from files locally or uploading to a server and displaying from there?

Comment: yeah you're right - i'm running the code through a CMS - I think somehow the CMS is changing the code. Thanks though - got me looking in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

```
function change_trend(){
     $('#trends_holder').animate({
       left: "50px", 
       opacity: 1
-->    }, );
}
```

comma with nothing after it.

```
function change_trend(){
     $('#trends_holder').animate({
       left: "50px", 
       opacity: 1
     }, 500);
}
```

Comment: I know that! What I'm saying is that I put the duration in - but something is stripping it out! I even removed absolutely everything from the script other than this one function, and it still removes the duration.

Comment: But ... in his **original** code, there **is** something after the comma. The part you quoted is the broken part he says is "rendered" in the browser, though it's not exactly clear what that means.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when copying code I've seen the quotes get converted to fancy MS-Word style quotations, which will break the code.